# Is this notation appropriate for multiple integrals of this form?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, notation

I am trying to write the following integral in an easier notation

$$
\int_0^\infty\ldots \int_0^\infty f(x_1,\dots,x_k)\,dx_1\ldots dx_k
$$

For example
$$
\int_0^\infty\ldots \int_0^\infty \prod_{i=3}^k e^{-x_i} \,dx_3\ldots dx_k
$$

Is the notation

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^k} f(x_1,\dots,x_k)\,dx_1\ldots dx_k
$$
correct?

Also, is it appropriate to write $dx_1\ldots dx_k$ in a simpler form?

Comment: No. You should write $d(x_1,x_2,..,x_k)$ instead of $dx_1,dx_2....dx_k$.

Comment: I would write it as $\int_{\mathbb{R}^k_+} f(x) dx$, or $\int_{\mathbb{R}^k_+} f dx$ or $\int_{\mathbb{R}^k_+} f$, but it depends on your audience.

Comment: @copper.hat, how would you write for example $
\int_0^\infty\ldots \int_0^\infty \prod_{i=3}^k e^{-x_i} \,dx_3\ldots dx_k
$

Comment: I would write the way you have in your comment.

Comment: A problem that makes this topic more opaque than it strictly needs to be is that it seems like every math & science subdiscipline that makes heavy use of multiple integrals has apparently designed their own notation. It really can be annoying sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you specify clearly that $\mathbb R_+^k$ means those points in $\mathbb R^k$ with all positive coordinates, you're fine.

But you could also write it like this:
$$\int_{\mathbf v\ge0}f(\mathbf v)\,d\mathbf v$$
This frees you from explicitly specifying the number of variables $k$. A similar notation is seen in the statement of the general Stokes theorem:
$$\int_{\partial \Omega} \omega = \int_\Omega d\omega$$
where $\Omega$ is some manifold, like $\mathbb R^k$ or $\mathbb R_+^k$.

Comment: my actual function is something like $\prod_{i=1}^k g(x_i)e^{-\lambda _i x_i}$ and sometimes $i$ starts from $2$ or $3$ not $1$ so I am not sure how I would use your $\mathbf v$ in this case.

Comment: for example $$
\int_0^\infty\ldots \int_0^\infty \prod_{i=3}^k e^{-x_i} \,dx_3\ldots dx_k
$$

Comment: @user3911153 Which exactly shows the utility of not having to define the number of variables. Just define $f(\mathbf v)=\prod_{i=a}^ke^{-v_i}$, etc.

Comment: so now $v=(x_3,\ldots,x_k)$?

Comment: @user3911153 No. You're only taking specific indices out of that vector, so don't change the vector, change the range of indices in the product.